# Why is all audio volume low at 100% in Windows 11?

Tags: audio, windows-11

Since installing Windows 11 on my newly built PC I have been struggling with low volume in general.

For example, if a video is playing on YouTube, the level monitor in “System -> Sound -> Output -> Volume” is only ~10%.

All Windows "Volume Mixer" settings are 100%.  Realtek "Speaker" setting is 100%. The programs producing the sounds are 100%.

In VLC I need to use a special setting to go into the hundreds of % to get the kind of volume I had on my old PC.

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue. Update all of your audio related drivers and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Update your Audio Driver for sure and possibly BIOS.

Check all the connections and card seating in your newly built PC. Double check your audio card (if separate).

Make sure your Power Supply is adequate:  All voltage rails proper and rated current not exceeded. Make sure overall PSU specification is adequate.

Make sure Windows 11 is up to date and that .NET Updates have been done as well.

Volume on 2 Production Windows 11 Pro machines here is normal at 40% volume and too high at 60%. A third Windows 11 Pro Insider machine as fine as well.

It is for sure not a Windows 11 problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an alternative opinion to the existing reply: I must say that this is a Windows 11 problem and it cannot be resolved using the system settings or advanced configurations.

The low sound relates not only to output devices but also to input devices. So, it is some kind of Windows sound level processing causing the problem.

I have faced it at least on 2 machines with completely different but relatively old hardware.
According to [this topic](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-volume-really-low/299d1dc0-fa52-4448-b130-092a59198258?page=1) other users experience the same problem. As far as I understand it is a Windows 11 by design behavior in relation to an older hardware component.

The only way the problem can be worked around is a third party software or use of alternative hardware. In my case, I was able to insert a USB sound card with fresh production date and connect headphones with a microphone to it. After that the sound level becomes relatively adequate, but of course the sound quality is poor. There is no solution for AUX port so far.